# Div Not Changing Color - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm just trying to make this div slowly change color when moused over. I've got this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#down").mouseover(function(){
        $("#down").animate({background: "#a34545"}, 5000)
    });
</script>
```

Shouldn't be that complicated, although I think I'll have to add a mouseout function as well. I tested what I have so far, and nothing happened. It just stayed the same color. What am I missing?

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Down-Champlain Regatta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topcontainer">
        <img src="Images/Kim.jpg" id="tom">
        <img src="Images/Kim.jpg" id="zach">

        <div id="head">
            <p id="a">Hello South Burlington. We're the</p>
            <h5>Down Champlain Regatta.</h5>
            <p id="s">And we've got a bold new plan for sailing education on Lake Champlain.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="down">
            <p>check it out</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#down").mouseover(function(){
                $("#down").animate({backgroundColor: "#a34545"}, 5000)
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought it might be my network blocking access to the jQuery library (school computer), so I downloaded the library and added the link, in the head. Does that look good to you guys? It's still not working...

Comment: can u attach html code as well?

Comment: Please make a Stack Snippet so the example is executable.

Comment: Why not `css transitions`?

Comment: True. With CSS transitions it would simply be `#down{transition: background 5s;} #down:hover{background: #a34545;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly working .

See this [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j7op02ch/1/)

just have to include  `jquery UI 1.8.5`
This is where the animate function of jquery came from.

See [Jquery Animate](http://jqueryui.com/animate/).

```
   Color Animation
Animate the properties of elements between colors.
```

Also  :
`$("#down").animate({background : "#a34545"}, 5000);`

should be    :
 `$("#down").animate({backgroundColor : "#a34545"}, 5000);`

Comment: Not quite. Your example runs the JS onLoad. His is run without any wrapping

Comment: I now include the library - jquery-1.11.2.js

Comment: @Tommay did my answer helped you? :) If its alright,can you check this as answer. Thanks. xD

Comment: Nope, still not working. Check the update. I posted the full HTML.

Comment: @Tommay have you downloaded the `jquery ui plug in`? also change your ` animate({background: "#a34545"} ` to  ` animate({backgroundColor : "#a34545"} `.see this http://jsfiddle.net/j7op02ch/2/

Comment: Hah, sorry, didn't see that. It's now backgroundColor... but it still doesn't work. Do I need jQuery UI for this? What is it exactly? I'm already linking to jQuery... I'm pretty sure...

Comment: Also you have to download the jquery UI so your animate method would work, download it from  http://jqueryui.com/ @Tommay

Answer (score 0):

You should have it inside of `$(document).ready`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#down").mouseover(function(){
            $("#down").animate({backgroundColor: "#a34545"}, 5000)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors.js
http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js

```
$('#demodiv').animate({backgroundColor: '#400101'})
```